# XPCOM DLL in Mozilla does not register

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I am creating a Firefox extension which contains an XPCOM DLL for Windows.
This DLL is built successfully (I followed the tutorial on http://briankrausz.com/building-a-c-xpcom-component-in-windows) and the DLL exports NSGetModule. I assume this should be OK.

I copied the IMyComponent.xpt and MyComponent.dll to the components directory of the extension.

In chrome.rdf I added:

```
interfaces components/IMyComponent.xpt
binary-component components/MyComponent.dll
```

However, the DLL is not registered. When I call the code in the JS code of my extension:

```
const cid = "@mydomain.com/XPCOMSample/MyComponent;1";
obj = Components.classes[cid].createInstance();
```

I get "TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined".

Do I miss anything to register the class?
How can I debug what's wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054143/mozilla-xpcom-is-not-registered

Comment: Not a duplicate - In the meantime I found out that the interface changed, the new interface is crappy and nearly noone seems to use XPCOM any more and I was recommended to use js-ctype. Conclusion: js-ctype worked out of the box :-)

Comment: What the hell does "the new interface is crappy" mean? You either need XPCom or you don't. There are a number of things you can do with XPCom that you can't do with `ctypes.jsm`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong words. I found out that the interface changed. Furthermore, on the mailinglist I was told that XPCOM is kind of deprecated. I should either use NPAPI or better js-ctypes for simpler tasks.

Comment: Well that's just wrong. If anything, `NPAPI` is essentially deprecated. `XPCom` is the most-used FFI interface, and `js-ctypes` is starting to get more adoption. But as I said, there are many things you just cannot implement (Mozilla-wise) via the ctypes interface. For example, there are quite a few cases now where folks implement JavaScript XPCom components that internally use js-ctypes for C++ FFI.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> js-ctype worked out of the box. NPAPI is essentially deprecated. XPCom is the most-used FFI interface, and js-ctypes is starting to get more adoption. There are many things you just cannot implement (Mozilla-wise) via the ctypes interface. For example, there are quite a few cases now where folks implement JavaScript XPCom components that internally use js-ctypes for C++ FFI.